# Rails 6 application with turbolinks doesn't load JS sometimes, I need to refresh the page. How do I fix that?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have taken over a Rails 6 app that is using turbolinks, in its Gemfile is following:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

I tried to add some external JS - it's a chatbot (this code is in the  tag):

```
  %script#hs-script-loader{:async => "", :defer => "defer", :src => "//<path-to-file>.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
```

When I load the website, everything works - all good. When I click on a link (that looks like this:

```
= link_to user_path(@user)
```

The chatbot doesn't work anymore - I need to refresh the page and then everything's works fine -  until I click another link within the app.

How do I solve this problem?

If this information is somehow useful - here's my `webpack/environment.js`:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require("webpack");

environment.plugins.append(
  "Provide",
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $:      "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery"
  })
);

module.exports = environment
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is impossible to actually answer without the code that actually doesn't work - the chatbot. My guess is that the chatbot makes some non-idempotent changes to the DOM like adding a container and then when turbolinks replaces the page it removes the elements needed for the chatbot to work. You can make elements persistent across page loads by adding the `data-turbolinks-permanent` attribute to the element. https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#persisting-elements-across-page-loads

Comment: Although the easiest option if you need a lot of incompatible dodads (like almost anything with jquery in the title) is to just remove turbolinks.

Comment: You can test removing the turbolinks  on the links too, like: link_to(user_path(@user), data: { turbolinks: false })